# How can I convert plain text password into PBKDF2 algorithm format in Django?

Tags: python, django, database, plaintext, pbkdf2

I have list user information that I am pulling from some other database tool. The information in this tool is in plain text. I am using Django for my project and I need passowrd into
`<algorithm>$<iterations>$<salt>$<hash>` format.

Which library or script that I can use to convert my plaintext to Hashed value ?

I have read about Django Hasher but wanted to get more information about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are gonna save the password in a user model, just call `user.set_password(<plain-text password>)` on the instance. Otherwise, use `make_password()`:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password

hashed_pass = make_password(plain_text_pass)
```